# How to implement this for loop in Python

Tags: python

Im trying to implement Radix Sort in Python. In the main Radix Sort function there is a for loop like this:

```
m = Maximum element in a given array
for(p = 1; m/p > 0; p*10)
{
    do stuff;
}
```

i did implement it using a while loop like below:

```
p = 1
while m / p > 0:
    p *= 10
    do stuff;
```

But since for loop is faster than while loop, I wonder how to implement that pseudocode in Python with a for loop. Any suggestions?

Note: Radix Sort uses counting sort to sort based on digits starting from the right most digit (p=1) to the last digit and that's why for loop is used.

Comment: What's the value of `m`?

Comment: The Python for loop doesn't work the same way. It's more comparable to "for-each" loops in languages with the type of for loop you're showing.

Comment: do you mean `p*=10` or `p*10`?

Comment: You could wrap your loop up into a function that creates a generator yielding `p`, `m`, or both values, and then write something like: `for m, p in generator(args): ...`

Comment: @OrangoMango m is the maximum value in the given array.

Comment: @OrangoMango p*=10 is the equivalent to m*10 in python while loop

Comment: if `m / p > 0` then `m/p*10` will also be >0,  for any given value of p.. this will run forever.

Comment: @JeffUK no it works perfectly fine. it is just the matter of converting this to a for loop.

Comment: So it will actually run until m/p reaches min_float,  that seems like a really arbitrary solution do you mean int(m/p)?  What property of p or m are we actually testing here?   i.e. loop once per digit in m?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well after doing a research on the loops topic, i found that using a string instead of doing calculation is much faster. It is not the correct answer but it is the fastest implementation in Python.

```
for _ in range(len(str(m)):
    do stuff
```

Comment: So you asked ```But since for loop is faster than while loop, I wonder how to implement that pseudocode in Python with a for loop. Any suggestions?``` and got two options with timings and bytecode analysis, including a comparision to your while loop hypothesis. Then you copy one of the solutions presented and answer the question yourself and mark it as accepted? Classy. Way to go man.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit 1:**

So I was curious and implemented the three discussed approches:

```
import time 
import dis
import math

m = 100
p = 1.0
print(f'm:{m}, p:{p}')

print('-- For range - log')
c = 0
start = time.process_time()
for _ in range(int(math.log10(m))+1):
    c += 1
end = time.process_time() - start
print(f'c: {c}')
print(f'time: {end}')
c = compile('for _ in range(int(math.log10(m))+1):\n\tc += 1', '<string>', 'exec')
dis.dis(c)

print('-- For range - str len')
c = 0
start = time.process_time()
for _ in range(len(str(int(m)))):
    c += 1
end = time.process_time() - start
print(f'c: {c}')
print(f'time: {end}')
c = compile('for _ in range(len(str(int(m)))):\n\tc += 1', '<string>', 'exec')
dis.dis(c)

print('-- While loop')
c = 0
start = time.process_time()
while int(m / p) > 0:
    p *= 10
    c += 1
end = time.process_time() - start
print(f'c: {c}')
print(f'time: {end}')
c = compile('while int(m / p) > 0:\n\tp *= 10\n\tc += 1', '<string>', 'exec')
dis.dis(c)
```

Which results on my machine to:

```
  -- For range - log
  c: 3
  time: 7.000000000000062e-06
    1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (range)
                2 LOAD_NAME                1 (int)
                4 LOAD_NAME                2 (math)
                6 LOAD_METHOD              3 (log10)
                8 LOAD_NAME                4 (m)
               10 CALL_METHOD              1
               12 CALL_FUNCTION            1
               14 LOAD_CONST               0 (1)
               16 BINARY_ADD
               18 CALL_FUNCTION            1
               20 GET_ITER
          >>   22 FOR_ITER                12 (to 36)
               24 STORE_NAME               5 (_)

    2          26 LOAD_NAME                6 (c)
               28 LOAD_CONST               0 (1)
               30 INPLACE_ADD
               32 STORE_NAME               6 (c)
               34 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           22
          >>   36 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
               38 RETURN_VALUE
  -- For range - str len
  c: 3
  time: 2.9999999999960614e-06
    1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (range)
                2 LOAD_NAME                1 (len)
                4 LOAD_NAME                2 (str)
                6 LOAD_NAME                3 (int)
                8 LOAD_NAME                4 (m)
               10 CALL_FUNCTION            1
               12 CALL_FUNCTION            1
               14 CALL_FUNCTION            1
               16 CALL_FUNCTION            1
               18 GET_ITER
          >>   20 FOR_ITER                12 (to 34)
               22 STORE_NAME               5 (_)

    2          24 LOAD_NAME                6 (c)
               26 LOAD_CONST               0 (1)
               28 INPLACE_ADD
               30 STORE_NAME               6 (c)
               32 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           20
          >>   34 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
               36 RETURN_VALUE
  -- While loop
  c: 3
  time: 2.9999999999960614e-06
    1     >>    0 LOAD_NAME                0 (int)
                2 LOAD_NAME                1 (m)
                4 LOAD_NAME                2 (p)
                6 BINARY_TRUE_DIVIDE
                8 CALL_FUNCTION            1
               10 LOAD_CONST               0 (0)
               12 COMPARE_OP               4 (>)
               14 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       34

    2          16 LOAD_NAME                2 (p)
               18 LOAD_CONST               1 (10)
               20 INPLACE_MULTIPLY
               22 STORE_NAME               2 (p)

    3          24 LOAD_NAME                3 (c)
               26 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
               28 INPLACE_ADD
               30 STORE_NAME               3 (c)
               32 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            0
          >>   34 LOAD_CONST               3 (None)
               36 RETURN_VALUE
```

Seems like the generator approach with string count as opposed to logarithm calculation is the fastes. My intution was that the while loop might be faster than the generator functions. Turns out, the generator using the log function is about 3 times slower, and the str length generator is about as fast than the while loop.

Fascinating.

**Original Answer:**

I assume the statement that for loops are faster than while loops is an untested hypothesis. So why not test it?

Put your implementations in a timed block:

```
import time
start = time.process_time()

# your code here    

end = time.process_time() - start
print(end)
```

Comment: The main reason that While is much slower is because the while loop checks the condition after each iteration.

Comment: @Sahar In relation to what? To a generator function? You use [for loops](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop) in python most likley with a range generator.

Comment: i have done it using a while loop but now i want to do it using for.

Comment: @Sahar Feel free to mark this answer as accepted and close the post, if this answered you question.

Comment: sorry but this is not the answer to the question.

Answer (score -1):

Logarithms are probably your answer. Don't be surprised though, if it wants to repeat like 13.0983 times or something. Also, unless m changes values, the while loop will forever run because it never will be 0 (unless there is rounding).

You also could just do:

```
for i in int((large p number calculated with while loop)/m):
    #code
```

Comment: I don't think this is correct.

Comment: This is incorrect, that is not how it works

Comment: This can not work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).