# Unable to get cython loop to run faster than pyhton loop

Tags: python, cython

I'm trying to speed up a python function by using cython, but without luck so far. The original python code is currently faster. If anyone have ideas on how the execution time can be lowered it would be appreciated.

Original python code.
slave_range_function.py:

```
import numpy as np

def slave_range(i0:np.array,i1:np.array,slave_shear:np.array):
    n=len(i0)
    shear_range =np.zeros(n)
    for i in range(n):
        i0_ = i0[i]
        i1_ = i1[i]
        sub_array = slave_shear[i0_:i1_]
        max_sub = sub_array.max()
        min_sub = sub_array.min()
        shear_range[i] = max_sub-min_sub
    return shear_range
```

The cython code: 
slave_range_cy.pyx:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
np.import_array()

INT_TYPE = np.int32
FLOAT_TYPE = np.float64

ctypedef np.int32_t INT_TYPE_t
ctypedef np.float64_t FLOAT_TYPE_t


def slave_range(np.ndarray[INT_TYPE_t, ndim=1] i0,np.ndarray[INT_TYPE_t, ndim=1] i1,
    np.ndarray[FLOAT_TYPE_t, ndim=1] slave_shear):
    cdef int n = i0.shape[0]
    cdef np.ndarray shear_range = np.zeros(n,dtype = FLOAT_TYPE)
    cdef int i0_
    cdef int i1_
    cdef FLOAT_TYPE_t max_sub
    cdef FLOAT_TYPE_t min_sub

    for i in range(n):
        i0_ = i0[i]
        i1_ = i1[i]
        max_sub = np.max(slave_shear[i0_:i1_])
        min_sub = np.max(slave_shear[i0_:i1_])
        shear_range[i] = max_sub-min_sub
    return shear_range
```

Setup file to compile cython code:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import numpy

setup(ext_modules=cythonize("slave_range_cy.pyx"),
      include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()])
```

Comment: How about benchmarking? You might find some inspiration in this [answer using timing and bytecode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70596457/949561) to analyse performance.

Comment: This is the standard problem that applies to almost every other "I can't get get speed improvement with Cython question": Cython can't look inside Numpy functions so doesn't magically speed those up.

Comment: I suggest using typed memoryviews instead of the old buffer syntax. Then implement your own `get_max(i0_, i1_)` and `get_min(i0_, i1_)` functions, using `cython.boundscheck(False)` (for example) and others. Finally, maybe use`prange` instead of `range`. Also, use `annotate=True` in your setup.py file to check for possible optimziations. Cython's docs has all the info to get you going.